# Заменить "-" на пробел

Tags: c#

Чтобы перевести строку в hex код, нужно применить этот код:

```
public static byte[] FromHex(string hex)
    {
        hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
        byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
        {
            raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }
        return raw;
    }
```

но проблема в том что строка выводится вся вместе без пробелов, т.к. срабатывает замена `"-",""`.... надо получить типа так: `"-"," "`, должно быть так: `"31-32-33"`,а не так `"313233"`
даже если я поменяю на пробел то выскакивает ошибка на эту строку

```
raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
```

Не удалось найти распазнаваемые цифры

в Main'e этот код:

```
byte[] data = FromHex(mystr);
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
s = s.Replace("-", "");
```

Comment: "Чтобы перевести строку в hex код, нужно применить этот код:" не вяжется с "FromHex". Очевидно вы невнимательно читали комментарии к этому методу там, где его нашли. Этот метод переводит строку, содержащую HEX-представление в массив байт и не более.

Comment: @rdorn вот где ввзял этот код
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724862/converting-from-hex-to-string

Comment: @rdorn но hex коды пишутся с пробелом и без "-" знаков

Comment: где пишутся, кем пишутся? данный метод ни чего не пишет, а преобразует hex в нормальные машинные байты

Comment: где и кем пишутся, я написал, код конвертирует строку хх-хх-хх...-хх вв строку читаемую, но строка(которая конвертируется) должна быть на подобии хх хх хх ... хх

Comment: разделитель мне нужен а не "-"

Comment: Так, еще раз. Что у вас на входе (пример реальных данных)? Что ждете на выходе (пример ожидаемого значения)?

Comment: вот такая строка hex на входе `string stroka = "31 32 33";`

Comment: `hex.Replace(" ", "")`

Comment: А это случайно не преобразование string-GUID в байты GUID? Для этого специальная одна функция есть. `(new Guid(hex)).ToByteArray()`

Comment: @nick_n_a та не, все норма!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может пробел пропущен?

```
s = s.Replace("-", " ");
```

Но после этого вы не сможете конвертировать hex т.к. в hex добавятся пробелы.

При этом вы возвращаете byte[] а не строку.

Если вы хотите получить из hex тип byte[], но при этом заменить `-` в вашем string на пробелы, то делайте

```
s = s.Replace("-", " ");
```

до выполнения вашей функции `public static byte[] FromHex(string hex)`

Примерно так

```
string string_ = s.Replace("-", " ");
byte[] byte_ = FromHex(string_);

public static byte[] FromHex(string hex)
```